# How can one test that a signal is High-Z when simulating with Verilator?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, verilator

Say I have this module:

```
module Test(
    input  logic a,
    output logic b
);

    assign output = a ? 1'bZ : 1'b1;

endmodule;
```

Currently, when testing the module with a C++ testbench, the output of the simulation shows the High-Z state as 0 (I assume because Verilator models logic lines as integers).

Is there any capability to test whether a `0` is a numerical `0` or a High-Z?

Comment: Is case equality (===) something that can help with your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. I believe you can write the expression `b === 'bz` within your SystemVerilog code, and that returns true (`1'b1`) within your code when `b` should have had a `z` state, but the actual output gets converted to a 0.